# Read only and write only using open()

Tags: c, shell, unix

I need to open one file just to read and anoter for writing - only write.

There is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
   if( argc != 2 ){
      printf( "Naudojimas:\n %s failas_ar_katalogas\n", argv[0] );
      exit( 255 );
   }

   int fd;

   fd = open( argv[1], O_RDONLY );
   if(fd == -1){
      printf("Nepavyko atidaryti skaitymui.\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   else {
      printf( "Failas %s skaitymui atidarytas.\n", argv[1] );
   }

   int fd1;

   fd1 = open( argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );
   if(fd1 == -1){
      printf("Nepavyko atidaryti rasymui.\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   else {
      printf( "Failas %s rasymui atidarytas.\n", argv[2] );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If I write just ONE argument, then I got output that first file successfully opened, but if I put TWO arguments I don't get output.

Expected results: file, which is mentioned at first argumentopened like read only, and file which is mentioned on second argument opened like write only (p.s. if there is no file with second argument, then it should be created, if its existed, just delete data from it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `argc` check is wrong. The value of `argc` is the number of valid elements in the `argv` array, *including* the "command" in `argv[0]`. If there's two arguments, then the value of `argc` will be `3`.

This should have been quite easy to see, primarily since if you provided two arguments to the program then the error message about it should have been written. And if you used a debugger then that should have made it obvious as well.

Comment: Ohh, damnn... Yes, thanks. One more question. Is my code written optimally?

Comment: @EdgarasAlšauskas "Optimally" like how? There's basically only one way to do what you do, and you do it that way. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I want to ask :D